# What's MonoPosixHelper.dll all about?

Tags: mono, posix, banshee

In my effort to learn more about cross-platform developping in C# I tried checking out the Banshee project. In it's current form it is not compiling.
So I'm trying to fix it up as far as my knowledge is stretching.

Firstly almost all of the projects have broken references. I thought this was the easiest part to fix. I thought wrong...
A reference that is often broken is the MonoPosixHelper.dll. I installed the Mono framework and in it's bin folder fount the MonoPosixHelper.dll file. When I tried to reference it Visual Studio complains that it's not a valid assembly or not a COM object. The latter I understand because it's not a com..

So, what does this library do exactly, why is it not a valid assembly and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a native DLL, and it helps the implementation of the Mono.Posix namespace. It provides pinvoke entry points to API provided by Mono.Posix, such as conversion functions that convert various C library and system call structures to managed structures.

You should not need to reference this library in a project at all.

Comment: So basically, I should be able to remove these references. I'll check tonight.